# How to get values from 3 tables?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spJoin3Tables
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        tbl_Jobs.JobTitle, tbl_Company.CompName
    FROM 
        tbl_Jobs
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_Company ON tbl_Jobs.CompID = tbl_Company.ID

    SELECT 
        tbl_Cities.CityName
    FROM 
        tbl_Cities
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_JobCities ON tbl_Cities.ID = tbl_JobCities.CityID
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_Jobs ON tbl_JobCities.JobID = tbl_Jobs.ID
END
```

The result is two tables. I want to get all three columns in one table - what will be the query?

Comment: what is relation between resulting 2 tables?

Comment: Describe how you want the different tables combined!

Comment: Is this a quiz? Sounds like one, for sure

Comment: I might be seeing double but looks to me like these are 4 tables: jobs, company, jobcities and cities

Comment: Yes these are 4 tables @JeremyC.

Comment: Well the answer has been given, if you change the second inner join "INNER JOIN tbl_Cities
ON tbl_JobCities.JobID = tbl_Jobs.ID" to "INNER JOIN tbl_JobCities
ON tbl_JobCities.JobID = tbl_Jobs.ID" then the answer by @Pranay Rana should work

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the company table and the columns from the first query to the second query and make sure to join on the company id.

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Cities.CityName, tbl_Jobs.JobTitle, tbl_Company.CompName
FROM 
    tbl_Cities
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_JobCities ON tbl_Cities.ID = tbl_JobCities.CityID
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Jobs ON tbl_JobCities.JobID = tbl_Jobs.ID
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Company ON tbl_Jobs.CompID = tbl_Company.ID
```

Comment: I want to retrieve those cities in which jobs are posted There is many-to-many relations b/w tbl_Jobs and tbl_Cities. @Sam

Comment: With how this query is written, you should get multiple rows for each job based on how many cities are in the JobCities table. Is that not what is happening?

Comment: Thats exactly happening but i want to retrieve those cities who's ID is in tbl_JobCIties as CityID. In your case i am getting all cities which are in tbl_Cities @Sam

Comment: Please look at this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36144/2. I recreated your table structure and showed how the query should works. All cities will be returned because you arent putting a where statement for the specific jobs you want

Answer (score 0):

USING INNER JOIN U CAN GET ALL DATE. IF IN CASE ANY TABLE IN ID COLUMNS NULL VALUE THEN USER LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT tbl_Jobs.JobTitle, tbl_Company.CompName , tbl_Cities.CityName
FROM tbl_Jobs
INNER JOIN tbl_Company ON tbl_Jobs.CompID = tbl_Company.ID
INNER JOIN tbl_JobCities ON tbl_JobCities.JobID = tbl_Jobs.ID
INNER JOIN tbl_Cities ON tbl_Cities.ID = tbl_JobCities.CityID
```

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS. It's difficult to read, and is often interpreted as shouting.